# How to get data out of $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want geting data out of jQuery podt, How can do it?

```
nat="";
$.post("random_unique", function(data){
    nat = data;
});
alert(nat); //--> Nothing.
```

Comment: Did you try **var nat = "";**

Comment: @Carlos487 that is not the issue.

Comment: Whatever you want to do where `alert(nat)` is, put it inside the function

Comment: Ok the problem is that the $.post call is asynchronous so yoy have to do it using the done() fail() and always() handlers to see the results after it executed

Answer (score 2):

jQuery calls are asynchronous, in that you can execute the remainder if your script while the data is still loading. Perform your tasks in the callback of your `$.post()`.

```
nat="";
$.post("random_unique", function(data){
    nat = data;
    alert(nat); //--> Something!
});
```

P.S. don't use `alert()` to debug code; use `console.log()`. If you receive a JSON response (or when you get into error handling) often times you'll be working with objects, which don't alert out.